# What happens to unhandled async errors in AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm trying to debug a problem that I think is being caused by an uncaught error in an async process. This is simple example that simulates the type of error I'm trying to detect:

```js
async function test(event, context) {
    console.log('I can find this log message');
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('I cannot find this one');
        throw new Error('uh oh'); // I don't see this in CloudWatch, either
    }, 1000);
    return {};
}
```

I know the lambda is frozen after the function returns, so I'm guessing there's no way to see these errors/logs.

**Is there anything I can do to try to detect what is still in the event loop when the handler returns so I might be able to track down an unhandled error like this one?**

Comment: Looks like I might be able to use something like this to see what's in the callback queue: https://github.com/mafintosh/why-is-node-running

Comment: `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = true;`

Comment: Unfortunately, I need it set to false for something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subscribe to the unhandled rejections.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => { // log error});
```

hope this helps.